# How can you speed up Fortran OpenMP?

Tags: performance, fortran, openmp

I’m working on a code that makes use of openMP. Unfortunately the code is still too slow for my purposes. I would greatly appreciate any suggestion on how to speed it up.

I tried to explain where the bottleneck is in the comments in the code: in step 4 there are three nested loops over x_c,b_c,k_c and inside there is another loop for a maximization. I parallelized with openMP only the outermost loop, the one over x_c.

I include below a **minimum working example** that you can easily replicate on your machine (I'm using windows with intel fortran, but the code should work also with gfortran). To compile it:
ifort /Qopenmp /O3 /Qipo /Qprec-div- sub_vfi_onestep_mex.f90 -o run.exe

```
module mymod
implicit none
    contains
    
    function linspace(my_start, my_stop, n)
    ! Purpose: replicate Matlab function <linspace>
    implicit none
    ! Inputs:
    integer :: n
    real(8) :: my_start, my_stop
    ! Function result:
    real(8) :: linspace(n)
    ! Locals:
    integer :: i
    real(8) :: step, grid(n)

    if (n == 1) then
        grid(n) = (my_start+my_stop)/2.0d0
    elseif (n>=2) then
        grid(1) = my_start
        if (n>2) then
            step = (my_stop-my_start)/(real(n-1,8))
            do i = 2, n-1
                grid(i) = grid(i-1) + step
            end do
        end if
        grid(n) = my_stop
    endif
    linspace = grid
    
    end function linspace
    !===============================================================================!
    
PURE FUNCTION locate(xx,x)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(8), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: xx
    REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: x
    INTEGER :: locate
    INTEGER :: n,il,im,iu
    n=size(xx)
    il=0
    iu=n+1
    do
        if (iu-il <= 1) exit
        im=(iu+il)/2
        if (x >= xx(im)) then
            il=im
        else
            iu=im
        end if
    end do
    if (x == xx(1)) then
        locate=1
    else if (x == xx(n)) then
        locate=n-1
    else
        locate=il
    end if
END FUNCTION locate
!===============================================================================!

PURE FUNCTION locate_equi(x_grid,xi) result(jl)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    ! Declare inputs
    REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: x_grid(:)
    REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: xi
    ! Declare function result 
    INTEGER :: jl
    INTEGER :: n
    REAL(8) :: step, xi_min 
    
    n      = size(x_grid)
    step   = x_grid(2)-x_grid(1)
    xi_min = xi-x_grid(1)
    
    jl     = min(n-1,max(1,floor(xi_min/step)+1))
    
END FUNCTION locate_equi
!===============================================================================!

pure subroutine find_loc(jstar,omega, a_grid,aopt) 
     implicit none
     ! Declare Inputs:
     real(8), intent(in) :: a_grid(:)
     real(8), intent(in) :: aopt
     ! Declare outputs:
     integer, intent(out) :: jstar
     real(8), intent(out) :: omega
     ! Declare local variables:
     integer :: na
     
     !Find j s.t. a_grid(j)<=aopt<a_grid(j+1)
     !for j=1,..,N-1
     ! omega is the weight on a_grid(j) and lies in [0,1]
 
     na = size(a_grid)
 
     jstar = locate_equi(a_grid,aopt)
     !Weight on a_grid(j)
     omega = (a_grid(jstar+1)-aopt)/(a_grid(jstar+1)-a_grid(jstar))
     !omega = max(min(omega,1.0d0),0.0d0)
     
end subroutine find_loc

FUNCTION linint(x,y,xi)
    ! Purpose: linear interpolation of function y on grid x at interpolation point xi
    !          To make it pure, cannot use PRINT or STOP statements
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(8), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: x,y
    REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: xi
    REAL(8) :: linint
    REAL(8) :: a,b,d
    INTEGER :: n,i
    n=size(x)
    IF (size(y)/=n) THEN
        PRINT *, 'linint: x and y must be of the same size'
        PAUSE
        STOP 'program terminated by linint'
    END IF
    ! If the grid x is NOT equally spaced, use "locate"
    ! otherwise use "locate_equi", faster.
    !i=max(min(locate(x,xi),n-1),1)
    i = locate_equi(x,xi)
    d = x(i+1)-x(i)
    !IF (d == 0.0) STOP 'bad x input in splint'
    a      = (x(i+1)-xi)/d
    b      = (xi-x(i))/d
    linint = a*y(i)+b*y(i+1)
END FUNCTION linint

function fun_adjcost(kprime,k,theta,delta) result(adj)
    implicit none
    ! Variables
    ! INPUTS
    ! kprime: Next-period capital, scalar
    ! k:      Current period capital, scalar
    ! theta:  Resale value, in (0,1)
    real(8), intent(in) :: kprime, k 
    real(8), intent(in) :: theta, delta 
    real(8) :: adj
    
    ! Body of fun_adjcost
    if (kprime>=(1.0d0-delta)*k) then
        adj = kprime-(1.0d0-delta)*k
    else
        adj = theta*(kprime-(1.0d0-delta)*k)
    endif
    
end function fun_adjcost
    
end module mymod
!===============================================================================!

subroutine sub_vfi_onestep(val_c_new,pol_kp,&
    val_c,val0_u,kp_bar,B_hat,profit_mat,k_grid,b_grid,pi_x,theta,q,delta,psi,nk,nb,nx)
    
    use omp_lib 
    use mymod, only: linint, fun_adjcost
    implicit none
    ! Declare input variables
    integer(4), intent(in) :: nk,nb,nx
    real(8), intent(in)    :: val_c(nk,nb,nx)
    real(8), intent(in)    :: val0_u(nk,nb,nx), kp_bar(nk,nb,nx)
    real(8), intent(in)    :: B_hat(nk,nx), profit_mat(nk,nx)
    real(8), intent(in)    :: k_grid(nk), b_grid(nk,nb), pi_x(nx,nx)
    real(8), intent(in)    :: theta, q, delta, psi
    ! Declare output variables
    real(8), intent(out)    :: val_c_new(nk,nb,nx)
    integer(4), intent(out) :: pol_kp(nk,nb,nx)
    ! Declare local variables
    integer(4) :: k_c, b_c, x_c, xp_c, kp_c, max_ind,h_c
    logical :: liq1, liq2
    real(8) :: k_val, b_val, profit_val, kp_ub, kp_val, bprime, v0_int
    real(8), allocatable :: EVx(:,:), b_grid_kp(:), rhs_vec(:)
    real(8), allocatable :: val0_c(:,:,:), val0(:,:,:)
    integer, allocatable :: is_c(:,:,:)
    
    ! The number of threads cannot be greater than the number of cores on the computer.
    call omp_set_num_threads(8)
    
    ! Initialize outputs
    val_c_new = 0.0d0 !(nk,nb,nx)
    pol_kp    = 1     !(nk,nb,nx)

    ! STEP 2 - Impose liquidation, eq. (24)

    ! Value of constrained firm before exit
    allocate(val0_c(nk,nb,nx))
    val0_c = 0.0d0
    do x_c = 1,nx
        do b_c = 1,nb
            do k_c = 1,nk
                k_val = k_grid(k_c)
                b_val = b_grid(k_c,b_c)
                profit_val = profit_mat(k_c,x_c)
                liq1 = profit_val-b_val+theta*(1.0d0-delta)*k_val<0.0d0
                liq2 = val_c(k_c,b_c,x_c)<theta*(1.0d0-delta)*k_val-b_val
                if (liq1 .or. liq2) then
                    val0_c(k_c,b_c,x_c) = theta*(1.0d0-delta)*k_val-b_val
                else
                    val0_c(k_c,b_c,x_c) = val_c(k_c,b_c,x_c)
                endif
            enddo
        enddo
    enddo
    
    ! STEP 3 - Do equation (23)
    allocate(val0(nk,nb,nx),is_c(nk,nb,nx))
    val0 = 0.0d0
    is_c = 1
    do x_c = 1,nx
        do b_c = 1,nb
            do k_c = 1,nk
                b_val = b_grid(k_c,b_c)
                if (b_val<=B_hat(k_c,x_c)) then
                    val0(k_c,b_c,x_c) = val0_u(k_c,b_c,x_c)
                    is_c(k_c,b_c,x_c) = 0
                else
                    val0(k_c,b_c,x_c) = val0_c(k_c,b_c,x_c)
                endif
            enddo
        enddo
    enddo
    
    ! STEP 4 - Solve eq. (25)
    
    allocate(EVx(nk,nb),rhs_vec(nk))
    
    ! Maximize over k' on the grid
    !$omp parallel default(shared) private(x_c,xp_c,b_c,k_c,EVx,k_val,b_val,profit_val,&
    !$ kp_ub,rhs_vec,kp_val,b_grid_kp,bprime,v0_int,max_ind) 
    !$omp do collapse(1)
    do x_c = 1,nx
        ! Compute expected value in eq. (25)
        EVx = 0.0d0 !(k',b')
        do xp_c = 1,nx
            EVx = EVx+val0(:,:,xp_c)*pi_x(x_c,xp_c)
        enddo
        do b_c = 1,nb
            do k_c = 1,nk                
                k_val = k_grid(k_c)
                b_val = b_grid(k_c,b_c)
                profit_val = profit_mat(k_c,x_c)
                kp_ub = kp_bar(k_c,b_c,x_c)

                if (is_c(k_c,b_c,x_c)==1 .and. profit_val-b_val+theta*(1.0d0-delta)*k_val>=0.0d0) then
                    ! If no forced liquidation
                    ! Set lower and upper bound for maximization over k' in (25)
                    ! b'>=b_grid(1)
                    !kp_lb = q*b_grid_k(1)+profit_val-b_val+k_val
                
                    ! Create the RHS of Bellman eq. 25 for each k' \in k_grid
                    rhs_vec = -100000.0d0
                    do kp_c = 1,nk
                        kp_val    = k_grid(kp_c)
                        b_grid_kp = b_grid(kp_c,:)
                        bprime = max(b_grid_kp(1), (1.0d0/q)*(b_val-profit_val+fun_adjcost(kp_val,k_val,theta,delta)))
                        if (kp_val<=kp_ub) then 
                            v0_int = linint(b_grid_kp,EVx(kp_c,:),bprime)
                            rhs_vec(kp_c) = q*(psi*(theta*(1.0d0-delta)*kp_val-bprime)+(1.0d0-psi)*v0_int)
                        else
                            exit    
                        endif
                    enddo !kp_c
                    max_ind = maxloc(rhs_vec,dim=1)
                    pol_kp(k_c,b_c,x_c)    = max_ind
                    val_c_new(k_c,b_c,x_c) = rhs_vec(max_ind)
                else
                    ! forced liquidation: val_c is irrelevant
                    val_c_new(k_c,b_c,x_c) = theta*(1.0d0-delta)*k_val-b_val
                endif
            enddo !k
        enddo !b
    enddo !x
    !$omp enddo
    !$omp end parallel

end subroutine sub_vfi_onestep   
!============================================================================! 

program main
use mymod, only: linspace
use omp_lib
implicit none

external :: sub_vfi_onestep ! better to put this into a module, but I can't
integer, parameter :: nx = 60  
integer, parameter :: nb = 80  
integer, parameter :: nk = 100 
real    :: t_end, t_start
integer :: x_c,k_c,istat
real(8) :: theta,q,delta,psi
real(8) :: k_grid(nk)
real(8) :: b_grid(nk,nb), pi_x(nx,nx)
real(8) :: B_hat(nk,nx), profit_mat(nk,nx) 
real(8), allocatable :: val_c(:,:,:), val0_u(:,:,:), kp_bar(:,:,:), val_c_new(:,:,:)
integer(4), allocatable :: pol_kp(:,:,:)
!pol_kp(nk,nb,nx)

write(*,*) "Hello, sub_vfi_onestep!"

! Create fake data

theta  = 0.9107133678d0
q      = 0.989d0
delta  = 0.015d0
psi    = 0.0029334045302853d0

! Equally spaced grids
k_grid = linspace(0.01d0,200.0d0,nk)

do k_c = 1,nk
    b_grid(k_c,:) = linspace(-100d0,50d0,nb)
enddo

! Right stochastic matrix pi_x, make sure all rows sum to one
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(pi_x)
do x_c = 1,nx
    pi_x(x_c,:) = pi_x(x_c,:)/sum(pi_x(x_c,:))
enddo

write(*,*) "sum(pi_x) rows = ", sum(pi_x,dim=2)

allocate(val_c(nk,nb,nx), val0_u(nk,nb,nx), kp_bar(nk,nb,nx), val_c_new(nk,nb,nx),&
    pol_kp(nk,nb,nx), STAT=istat)
if (istat/=0) then
    write(*,*) "Allocation failed!"
endif

CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(B_hat)
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(profit_mat)
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(val0_u)
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(kp_bar)
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(kp_bar)
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(val_c)

! Call the computational subroutine "sub_vfi_onestep"
! NOTE: would be better to use assumed shape dummy arguments but I can't change this
write(*,*) "Calling sub_vfi_onestep.."
t_start = omp_get_wtime()

call sub_vfi_onestep(val_c_new,pol_kp,&
    val_c,val0_u,kp_bar,B_hat,profit_mat,k_grid,b_grid,pi_x,theta,q,delta,psi,nk,nb,nx)

t_end = omp_get_wtime()
write(*,*) "..done!"

write(*,*) 'FORTRAN executable runs for',real(t_end-t_start),'seconds.'

pause

end program main
```

Comment: Having profiled this, what can you tell us about where the performance bottlenecks and parallelization ineffeciencies are?

Comment: *the code is still too slow for my purposes* That's kinda true for all parallel programs all the time.  Have you been able to quantify the gap between your code's use of available resources, and the capabilities of those resources (eg flops, RAM, memory bus, ...) ?

Comment: @francescalus The bottleneck is in STEP 4 (indicated in the comments), in particular in the 3 nested loops (x_c,b_c,k_c) which have inside an inner loop over kp_c. Please note that I tried to parallelize all three loops (x_c,b_c,k_c) with the directive do collapse(3), since there are no dependencies, but the code becomes slower

Comment: How many threads are you using? How does the performance vary with the number of threads? How many cores does the computer you are using have?

Comment: 1. Is step 4 the bottleneck? do a sequential timing. What percentage of the time goes into that loop? 2. How much does that loop speed up?

Comment: @IanBush I am using 8 threads, see the line call omp_set_num_threads(8). My pc has 8 physical cores and 16 threads. Do you suggest using 16 instead of 8?

Comment: I suggest looking at the performance on 1, 2, 4 and 8 threads, and telling us what the numbers are. If it scales the problem is not with OpenMP. If it doesn't scale the problem might be with OpenMP. At the moment we don't know - and can't test because the results you are interested in are on your computer, and we don't have access to that.

Comment: @IanBush I set call omp_set_num_threads(x) with x=1,2,4,8, where x is the number of threads used. The run timeresults are as follows: Number of cores     Time (seconds)

8                    0.125
4                    0.75
2                    0.875
1                    1.5 So overall openMP leads to an improvement of 1.5/0.125=12 times?

Comment: @Alessandro I'm not sure if omp_get_wtime() can be used outside of a parallel region. Besides, I wonder if the size of your problem is not too small for a reliable timing.

Comment: @Alessandro I have timed your code on Linux, compiled with ifort and same options than yours. Because it runs quite fast I have called ```sub_vfi_onestep()``` 1000 times (I first tried to increase nx/nk/nb but got a segfault)... 1 thread --> 37", 2 threads --> 21", 4 threads --> 13", 8 threads --> 9". Then I have parallelized also the loops of STEP 2 and 3 and got 8" on 8 threads. So, your code doesn't scale extremely well (4.5x speed-up on 8 threads), but it's not too bad. If you really need to make it faster then you probably have to look after algorithmic optimisations (if possible).

Comment: @Alessandro I have managed to run the code with 4x all the sizes and time it (```sub_vfi_onestep()``` called 10 times): 1 thread --> 152", 8 threads --> 25". This is a 6x speed-up, so the code scales better with higher sizes (which is quite usual).

Comment: @Alessandro And finally I have specifically timed the STEP 4 loop alone. With original sizes: 1 thread --> 32 ms, 8 threads --> 5ms (6.4x speed-up). With 4x the sizes: 1 thread --> 17.4", 8 threads --> 2.3"ms (7.6x speed-up). So finally I would say that OpenMP does well on this code.

Comment: @PierU thanks for running the code and verifying the timing!